# Find volume of cube

Tags: geometry

I was given a cube that has a volume of $729$ cubic units. How do I find the length of one side of a cube? I know that $V = l \times w \times h$, where $l$ is length, $w$ is width, and $h$ is height. I was wondering if I may ask for some help here.

Comment: By definition, all sides of a cube are equal, does that hint help you?

Answer (score 1):

Let the side length be $l$. All sides are equal, so $l \times l \times l=l^3=729.$ Solve for $l$.

Comment: So I take the cube root on both sides, right?

Comment: Yup! And then you're good to go.